# How to Get started with MapKit in iPhone

Tags: iphone, dictionary

I am new bie to objective c i have worked with uikit only now i want to create an application which will be showing the colleges around me and its distance in a tableview.

So how to get started please suggest me.

How do i embed map in iPhone.

Thanks in advance.
aamir

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial/) is a good place to start!